# Html file in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hey guys im new to ios programming and new to objective C.  My question is is it poosible to display a html file that is stored in the supporting files folder to display in a webview upon click of a button.

Comment: yes. google `UIWebView`

Comment: i already have a webview on the home screen...but is it possible to multiple webviews that are used as buttons

Comment: Multiple web views used as buttons? What does that mean?

Comment: im able to create the different view but when it comes down to adding the code to the ViewController.m file is there a way differeniate which  webview goes to which link

Comment: what it means is that when i click a button is opens a webview that displays a different link that is on the home screen

Comment: im used to how things work in the android development cycle thats why i ask if there is a way to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load a local HTML file within the app, then use the below code

```
 self.wView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:INDEX_PAGE ofType:@"html" inDirectory:DIRECTOY_PATH]]; //Directory Path Example: ipad/main/pages
    [self.wView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Put this code in your button handler method